# Laravel 8.15.0/Jetstream - How to register new blades x-jet-newblade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

I am just doing my very first steps with Laravel 8 and found a problem that I can not solve.

`/var/www/html/laravel/resources/views/dashboard.blade.php`:

```
    <div class="py-12">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-xl sm:rounded-lg">
            <x-jet-welcome />
        </div>
```

If i create a new blade in the same directory (f.e. the form.blade.php) with the same code as above but with `<x-jet-subform/>` instead of `<x-jet-welcome>` it should normally redirect to the subform.blade.php which is located under `var/www/html/laravel/resources/views/vendor/jetstream/components/subform.blade.php`

But if I try to get to that page (after setting a Route at web.php) it says

> InvalidArgumentException
> Unable to locate a class or view for component [jet-subform].

So I think it's necessary to "register" new blades but I found no way to do that...

The view is already published with

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=jetstream-views
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was dealing with the same problem here and found your question unanswered.
The solution I found was to create my own new Blade component.
You can do that using:

```
$ php artisan make:component MyComponent
```

This will create two new files /resources/views/components/my-component.blade.php and /app/View/Components/MyComponent.php.
Now you just need to build your component on that blade file and reference it using the x-tag like this:
`<x-my-component></x-my-component>`

This is how the blade component code should look like

```
<button {{ $attributes->merge(['type' => 'button', 'class' => 'some-classes']) }}> {{ $slot }} </button>
```

Hope it helps. Greetings from Brazil :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! It worked for me but I've no idea why it's not possible to use the Jetstream Blade instead of a "normal" Blade component.

Comment: In a tutorial, he claims you can add a new component by creating a new component blade file inside the `views/components` folder, but  I get that error: `Unable to locate a class or view for component`. Do I really have to execute `make:component`. Can it simply get done by adding a new blade file, as @operator is asking for?

Comment: Kind of wish I had not down voted this (sorry), but I don't think it answers the question pricisely, which seems specific to jetstream.  I think the answer submitted by @Saravanakumar is more accurate.

Answer (score 18):

You can register your jetstream blade components in `App\Providers\JetstreamServiceProvider.php` located in `app\Providers` folder.

Add the following helper function to the file:

```
protected function registerComponent(string $component) {
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::component('jetstream::components.'.$component, 'jet-'.$component);
}
```

Then use the following snippet in register function to register your jetstream blade components:

```
public function register() {
    $this->registerComponent('subform');
}
```

Now you can use your custom jetstream component:

```
<x-jet-subform>
```

Comment: This worked well, but the blade location is important.  I had to place it in resources/views/vendor/jetstream/components in order for it to be recognized.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I don't get why this has to be done manually. Is there some update in planning?

Comment: They should include this part on the jetstream's documentation IMO

Answer (score 0):

I think this post helps out some people in **2023 upwards** since there have been some changes with **using PHP 8.1+ and Laravel 10** now.

@Isaac Pontes
made a really good post 3 years ago to add components manually. This actually should be in the Jetstream official documentation but it seems it's not maintained really well which makes Jetstream really a small niche and hard to find good solutions.

However, please see this code to solve the same issue OP had:

```
class JetstreamServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        $this->registerComponent('label');
        $this->registerComponent('form-section');
        $this->registerComponent('action-message');
        $this->registerComponent('section-title');
        $this->registerComponent('confirms-password');
        $this->registerComponent('input-error');
    }

    protected function registerComponent(string $component) {
        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::component('vendor/jetstream/components/'.$component, 'jet-'.$component);
    }
```

With this you will register JetStream components manually and directly point to the `vendor/jetstream/components` path which should be in your `resources` folder.

In `register()` you can add all missing components each page view manually. I am mainly building my components myself but I still have some exceptions where I use JetStream components. That will help anyone else that goes the same route.

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure whether it's the correct or intended way to add new custom x-jet components here as this method may not survive an update, but you can register new components in this file:

> `vendor/laravel/jetstream/src/JetstreamServiceProvider.php`.

Add, `$this->registerComponent('subform');` to the configureComponents method, and then call it with an `<x-jet-subform>` tag

Comment: As you already wrote, this solution will not survive a package update.